# How to display mongoDB cursor in a jsp file

Tags: mongodb-java

I am just trying some code with mongodb..
The cursor I am showing on a jsp is by iterating over the cursor..

Is there a simpler way to display mongoDb cursor on jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use skip and limit to page through the results.